# Create a mobile site for already existing Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, mobile-website

I want to build a mobile website for an already existing Wordpress site. I prefer to redirect the users to the mobile site automatically if the user is browsing from a mobile device. I will also need to change the contents of the pages regularly and may have to add more pages over time. But I do not want to create two different copies of the same page for desktop and mobile.

Please suggest the best option to go forward with this situation.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JezenThomas, I do not want it to be responsive, I want to add a dedicated site for mobile, like m.example.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you would pretty much have to design your theme to dynamically change what it's doing as needed.  This might just be a matter of activating the right style sheets or it might be more complicated.

There's a good book on this subject you might want to check out.

[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Development-WordPress-Programmer-ebook/dp/B004T6RKT0/ref=dp_kinw_strp_1?ie=UTF8&m=AG56TWVU5XWC2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004T6RKT0)

Comment: Thanks Mike, I'm all game for designing a new theme, but is it possible to create two front-ends on the same DB with wordpress?

Comment: The meaning of "two front ends" is not quite clear, but if you mean having a setup where you have what amounts to two separate sites with different themes accessing the same database, I don't think that will work right. The theme is set in the database, and I don't think you can change it dynamically at runtime.

I don't think it's a problem to run the same setup with the same theme on something like "m.mysite.com" and "www.mysite.com" however.  And you could program the theme to look at the domain name and format the output accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You want two sites with the same content, but you don't want to enter the content twice, and for some reason you don't want the site to be responsive. That makes things difficult.

Theoretically you could have both sites taking their information from the same database but in reality it just makes so much more sense to build a responsive site.

In any case, if you must have two sites, you can start by detecting mobile devices with [this PHP class](http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/).

Comment: Thanks @jezen, I did think of getting the data from the same db too and using it on two front-ends. The client wants it that way, that's is why I'm going forward with this method.

Comment: @RahulRamesh Does the client *really* want it that way? This brings to mind three things: [this](http://bit.ly/NRA3gj) and [this](http://bit.ly/Q45EPm) and [this](http://bit.ly/LECUsO).